# Axios set Content-Length manually, nodeJS

Tags: node.js, axios, content-length, http-content-length

Is there a way to send a post request in nodeJS and specify th content-length.

I tried (using axios):

```
let data = `Some text data...........`;

let form = await Axios.post(
    "url.......",
    data,
    {
        headers: {
            Authentication: "token.....",
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=c9236fb18bed42c49590f58f8cc327e3",
            //set content-length manually 
            "Content-Length": "268"
        }
    }
).catch(e => e);
```

It doesn't work, the length is set automatically to a value other then the one I pass.

I am using axios but open to using any other way to post from nodeJS.

Comment: why do you need to do that? this setting is populated automattically.

Comment: @Ashish Modi I was having issues and was trying to debug, I actually solved my issue without setting the content-length manually.

Comment: this is what `got` doc'n says - The content-length header will be automatically set if body is a string / Buffer / fs.createReadStream instance / form-data instance, and content-length and transfer-encoding are not manually set in options.headers.

Answer (score 5):

I can't add a comment because of low reputation, but part of Sandeep Patel's answer regarding `Axios` is outdated. You can set `Content-Length` manually. `Axios` will not override `Content-Length` if `content-length` header is present:

```
// Add Content-Length header if data exists
  if (!headerNames['content-length']) {
    headers['Content-Length'] = data.length;
  }
```

Source: https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/main/lib/adapters/http.js#L209-L213

So in your case it would be:

```
let data = `Some text data...`;

let form = await Axios.post(
    "url...",
    data,
    {
        headers: {
            Authentication: "token....",
            "Content-Type": "contentType...",
            //set content-length manually 
            "Content-Length": "268",
            "content-length": "268"
        }
    }
).catch(e => e);
```

Comment: Notice the difference in upper case / lower case: Axios sets `Content-Length` (upper case) if there is no `content-length` (lower case). So you set a `Content-Length` (upper case), as you did in your example, it might still be overwritten by axios.

Comment: @kca At the time of writing my answer I did some testing, and Axios did not overwrite the `Content-Length`

Comment: Sorry, "as you did in your example" was wrong here: I didn't mean _your_ example Dawid Piechota, I meant the example in the question by Shmili Breuer.

Answer (score 2):

In `Axios`, If data is present it will set length calculated from data, so even if you pass header `content-length`, it will be overridden by code:
[image]

Check this out for more details:
https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/adapters/http.js

**Using `http` or `https` module you can do:**

```
const https = require('https')

const data = JSON.stringify({
  key:values
})

const options = {
  hostname: 'example.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/testpath',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': data.length
  }
}
const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d)
  })
})

req.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error(error)
})

req.write(data)
req.end()
```